# Are "KeyboardEvent.key" values consistent cross-browsers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keyboard, cross-browser, keyboard-events

I'm building this component and I'm relying on `event.key` values in the `onKeyDown` handler to allow / disallow some inputs.

**DOCS:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

```
const ALLOWED_KEYS = [
  "Ctrl", "Meta", "Shift","Home", "End", 
  "Backspace", "Delete", 
  "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "Tab"
];

// ....

function onKeyDown(event) {
  if (ALLOWED_KEYS.indexOf(event.key) >= 0) {
    console.log("Allowed...");
  }
  else {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("NOT allowed...");
  }
}
```

Are those names consistent across browsers? Can I be sure that `ArrowRight` will be `ArrowRight` on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, etc? Or should I use some kind of `key` code value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html) you have all the `keycodes` according to [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/), which are cross browser. Those are the keycodes you want to use. You can type arrowLeft, right or backspace or whatever to find the corresponding `keyvalue` to that key.

This tool is quite handy so you might save this link somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but does it mean the the `event.key` values as strings are not consistent?

Comment: You're welcome :) I do not know about that, you can figure it out by running your project on different browsers. But the question is : why use strings? You have keycodes that are 100% cross-browsers, so you may want to use those instead.

Comment: that would be for better readability. But I'll run some tests! Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, after further testing, this does not work for mobile. The W3 testing tool show `code 229` for basically every digits, comma or point. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61248020/best-way-to-detect-typed-key-on-different-systems-and-keyboards

Answer (score 1):

Across most browsers it should work just fine.

The names are a W3 standard:

https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents-key/#named-key-attribute-values

But you won't be able to read `event.key` or `event.keyCode` in **Mobile Chrome for Android**.

There is a Chromium bug on this.

Long discussion in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

Comment: The return value of Event.key differs for example for the arrow keys in modern browsers like chrome `ArrowUp` and old browsers like IE11 `Up`. Is it now best practice to query both spellings?