# Best way to detect typed key on different systems and keyboards? Chrome mobile keyCode bug

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-chrome, chromium

I'm working on this special input and I need to allow / disallow some keys from being typed by the user.

I'm doing the validation on the `onKeyDown` handler.

This is what I was doing at first:

```
const ALLOWED_KEYS = [
  "Ctrl", "Meta", "Shift","Home", "End", 
  "Backspace", "Delete", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight", "Tab", 
  "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
  ".", ","
];

function onKeyDown(event) {
  if (ALLOWED_KEYS.indexOf(event.key) === -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

But I was worried that the string names of the keys were not consistent across browsers, so someone here on SO told me that I should change to `event.keyCode` instead of `event.key`.

And on this link I could check each key code:
https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

```
const DIGITS_COMMA_POINT_KEY_CODES = [
  48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,        // 0-9 NORMAL KEYBOARD
  96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,  // 0-9 NUMERIC KEYPAD
  110,188,                              // COMMA NORMAL AND NUMERIC KEYPAD
  190,194                               // POINT NORMAL AND NUMERIC KEYPAD
];

function onKeyDown(event) {
  if (DIGITS_COMMA_POINT_KEY_CODES.indexOf(event.keyCode) === -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Anyway, both options were working on Chrome Desktop, but failing in Chrome Mobile.

When I test the `keyCodes` from my Android mobile device I get completely different numbers:

Example:

```
KEY CODES FOR THE CHAR "0"

DESKTOP NORMAL KEYBOARD : 48
DESKTOP NUMERIC KEYPAD : 96
ANDROID MOBILE KEYBOARD : 229  (EVERY DIGIT SHOW AS 229)

-----------------

KEY CODES FOR THE CHAR "," (COMMA)

DESKTOP NORMAL KEYBOARD : 188
DESKTOP NUMERIC KEYPAD : 110
ANDROID MOBILE KEYBOARD : 229   (EVERY DIGIT, COMMA AND POINT SHOW AS 229)
```

PS: On Android Mobile, all the digits, comma and point seem to return `keyCode` as `229` on https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html

**UPDATE1:**

Just tested with `event.charCode` but every key logs as `charCode: 0`

**UPDATE2:**

On this link: https://javascript.info/keyboard-events
Every key from my Android Chrome Mobile shows up as `Unidentified`. This is weird.

**UPDATE3:**

This is an issue with Chrome Mobile. Firefox Mobile handles it perfectly. Haven't tested on other browsers.

[Keycode is always zero in Chrome for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139039/keycode-is-always-zero-in-chrome-for-android)

And this bug was reported in Chromium in 2012:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

**QUESTION**

What is the universal way to detect the typed key that should work on every keyboard, browser or system?

Comment: @stacks Nothing works. There's a work around this. I got to keep track of the `caretPosition` and react the `char` at that position to get the `charCode`. And be aware that `charCode` might not be the same as the `keyCode`.

Comment: Nice work! Yes I know that. This is quite strange but at least we learnt together about key events! I upvoted your post before so somebody could answer you but unluckily nobody came at the right time.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm also facing this issue and not being able to detect Backspace on custom android keyboards. The native android keyboard works though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From all the research that I did, here is the answer:

If you plan to support **Chrome Mobile on Android**, **DO NOT** use `onKeyDown` (and probably other `KeyboardEvents` such as `onKeyPres` and `onKeyUp`) because you **will not be able to read the keys that are being typed.**

This is a **Chromium** bug. The same happens on my **Samsung Internet**, since it's also Chromium-based.

There's an issue opened about this topic on Chromium since 2012. And I'm writing this in 2020.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118639

And there are heated discussions going on in there for the past 8 years.

This problem does not happen in **Android Firefox**, but somehow this is not a trivial thing to fix in Chromium. Don't know why.

---

I was looking for a solution for this, because when you call `event.preventDefault` inside the `onKeyDown` handler, you do not get a caret jump (at least on Mobile Chrome you don't). While if you are fixing the input value in the `onChange` handler you will need to deal with caret jumps.

I've ended up dealing with the caret jumps.

**EDIT**: It is not a bug anymore, as in the status of the bug you shared is **wontFix**

Answer (score 1):

I used `beforeInput` handler which works with both `textarea` and `input` tags. You can read more about this handler [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/input-events-1/). I found the `inputType` to vary across devices -- it was `insertText` on Mac Chrome browser and `insertCompositionalText` on Chrome Android Browser. To test on various devices, I played around with this JSFiddle `beforeInput` example - https://jsfiddle.net/mq5b9v0n/4/

Regardless, it seemed to work for me. Here's an updated version of your code:

```
function beforeInput(event) {
  if (ALLOWED_KEYS.indexOf(event.data) === -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```